# For Each loop Error :- java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8

Tags: android, foreach

For Below Code i am getting Error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.bss.client.righterapplication, PID: 20516
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8

I need to remove "None" from List.

```
private void createNameList(){

        arrayListTagNames.clear();
        int i=0;
        ArrayList<Integer> remArray=new ArrayList<>();
        for (TagClass name : arrayListTags){
            if (!name.getName().equals("None"))
                arrayListTagNames.add(name.getName());

            else
                remArray.add(i);
            i++;
        }
        Log.d("arrays0", arrayListTags.toString());
        Log.d("arrays0", String.valueOf(arrayListTags.size()));
        Log.d("arrays1", arrayListTagNames.toString());
        Log.d("arrays2", remArray.toString());
        Log.d("arraySize1 ", String.valueOf(arrayListTagNames.size()));
        Log.d("arraySize2 ", String.valueOf(remArray.size()));
        //arrayListTags.removeAll(remArray);
       // arrayListTags.removeAll(remArray);

           for (int index : remArray){

          arrayListTags.remove(index);

               Log.d("indexarraylist", arrayListTags.toString());
           }
        Log.d("array  ALT ", arrayListTags.toString());
    }
```

Comment: arrayListTags? wt is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose arrayListTags size is 5 and "none" is at index 3 and index 5
Now you removed index 3  so your arrayListTags size is 4 and your index 5 is now index 4 and u are trying to remove value at index 5 and giving out of index.
Try

```
// Get an iterator.
    Iterator<TagClass> ite = arrayListTags.iterator();
    while (ite.hasNext()) {
        TagClass value = ite.next();
        if (value.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("None"))
            ite.remove();


    }
}
```

arrayListTags will be modified and will have values excluding where
 name is None.

Answer (score 0):

You should use normal for loop instead of for each.

replace your for each to for.

```
for (int i = 0 : i < arrayListTags.size() : i++)
{
    if (!name.getName().equals("None"))
        arrayListTagNames.add(name.getName());

    else
        remArray.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your `arrayListTags.remove(index);` code because here you are not checking the size of arraylistTags which is not more or equal to the removing index position so it is giving array **IndexOutOfBoundEception**. Just check it out this code:

```
    private void createNameList() {
    if(arrayListTagNames==null){
        arrayListTagNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    arrayListTagNames.clear();

    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> remArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TagClass name : arrayListTags) {
        if (!name.getName().equals("None")) {
            arrayListTagNames.add(name.getName());
        } else {
            remArray.add(i);
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (arrayListTags != null && arrayListTags.size() > 0) {
        Log.d("arrays0", arrayListTags.toString());
        Log.d("arrays0", String.valueOf(arrayListTags.size()));
    }

    if (arrayListTagNames != null && arrayListTagNames.size() > 0) {
        Log.d("arrays1", arrayListTagNames.toString());
        Log.d("arraySize1 ", String.valueOf(arrayListTagNames.size()));
    }

    if (remArray != null && remArray.size() > 0) {
        Log.d("arrays2", remArray.toString());
        Log.d("arraySize2 ", String.valueOf(remArray.size()));
    }

    for (int index : remArray) {
        //Remove index if that is available for arrayListTag list
        if(index<arrayListTags.size()) {
            arrayListTags.remove(index);
        }

        if (arrayListTags != null && arrayListTags.size() > 0) {
            Log.d("indexarraylist", arrayListTags.toString());
        }
    }

    if (arrayListTags != null && arrayListTags.size() > 0) {
        Log.d("array  ALT ", arrayListTags.toString());
    }
}
```